# Can dimensions be passed to a variable within an XArray Dataset?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm currently working on a project that involves clipping Xarray datasets based on a certain grid of latitude and longitude values. To do this, I've imported a file with the specified lats and lons, and added dimensions onto the dataset to give it the necessary lat/lon information. However, I also want to pass the dimensions to a data variable (called 'precip') within the dataset. I know that I'm able to pass the dimensions to the array of values in the variable, but can they be passed to the variable itself?

My code is below:

```
precip = obs_dataset_full.precip.expand_dims(lon = 350, lat = 450)
precip.coords['Longitude'] = (-1 * (360 - obs_dataset_full.Longitude))
precip.coords['Latitude'] = obs_dataset_full.Latitude
precip
```

With output as such:
xarray.Dataset

Dimensions:
dim_0: 350 dim_1: 451 lat: 450 lon: 350

Coordinates:

dim_0
(dim_0)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 345 346 347 348 349

dim_1
(dim_1)
int64
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 446 447 448 449 450

Longitude
(lon)
float64
-105.7 -105.7 ... -78.34 -78.26

Latitude
(lat)
float64
35.04 35.08 35.11 ... 51.52 51.56

Data variables:

precip
(dim_0, dim_1)
float64
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 nan
Attributes: (0)

Specifically, I want the data variable precip to also possess dimensions of lat and lon, as the dataset does.

Thanks in advance!